call after = name after? [American English question]

(1) That baby is called after his grandfather.
(2) That baby is named after his grandfather.

It seems that (1) means (2), but none of my dictionaries has the phrasal verb "call someone after someone".
Is (1) normal in American English?

Name after is normal in AmE.

The English spoken in parts of the US and Canada is influenced by Irish-English. There are places in North America where you might hear "called after".

@TimR - don't many Americans say 'named for' (rare in British English)?  E.g. My oldest is named for his father but has always gone by his middle name. I know some say 'for' is only for things, but I don't see much evidence that people abide by that.

Yes, named for is also viable in AmE.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+named+for%2Cis+named+after%2Cis+called+after&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3

To my American English ears, these mean the same thing:
He is named after his grandfather.
He is named for his grandfather.
He is called "John" after his grandfather.
What is a little unusual, but not unheard of, is: "He is called after his grandfather" -- without including the name.
By the way, to "call after" someone can be a colloquial way of saying "contact" -- "She went to call after Joan, but she wasn't home." This is a variation of "to call on" someone.
Prepositions are tricky in AmEng. Their usage in common phrases doesn't always make logical sense; many uses are just traditional.

All three also sound acceptable to me in British English
